How to return custom header from lambda using REST API Gateway non proxy integration
I've setup a REST API gateway non-proxy integration
I have this NodeJS lambda code when responding with 200OK
return {
          statusCode: 200,
          headers: {"Content-type": "application/json", "set-cookie": "please-work"},
          body: JSON.stringify(response)
       };

REST API gateway - Method response:
Here I've defined the set-cookie header
REST API gateway - Integration response:
I have this setup:

Question:
You can see that I do map the set-cookie header to the response set-cookie header.
But still I do not see this header returned back to client - Why? How can I pass set-cookie header or any other to client?

LAMBDAS AND COOKIE RELATED HEADERS
Consider an HTTP response with these headers. Note that set-cookie can occur multiple times:
set-cookie: access-token=aDeSh7bC0qsTb...; Path=/; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=Strict
set-cookie: refresh-token=W16w1dU4N7pZM...; Path=/refresh; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=Strict
x-csrf: abc123

You can represent that with code like this, where the lambda object model supports both single value headers and multi value headers:
const handler = async (event: APIGatewayProxyEvent) : Promise<APIGatewayProxyResult> => {

    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: {
            "x-csrf": "abc123"
        },
        multiValueHeaders: {
            "set-cookie": [
                cookieSerializer.getAccessTokenCookieString(),
                cookieSerializer.getRefreshTokenCookieString(),
            ]
        }
        body: JSON.stringify({})
   };
}

OBJECT MODEL
If you look at TypeScript type definitions, you see the structure of the lambda response:
export interface APIGatewayProxyResult {
    statusCode: number;
    headers?:
        | {
            [header: string]: boolean | number | string;
        }
        | undefined;
    multiValueHeaders?:
        | {
            [header: string]: Array<boolean | number | string>;
        }
        | undefined;
    body: string;
    isBase64Encoded?: boolean | undefined;
}

GATEWAY RESPONSES
I'm pretty sure you shouldn't need to do anything in the AWS API gateway to receive the response. Usually you only do so when you need to customise error responses.
